# Expected Value of 3 numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I don’t understand expected value, can somebody tell me and help me do this problem?

Comment: "*I don't understand expected value.*"  What don't you understand about it?  Have you at least seen the definition of expected value?  What part of the definition do you have difficulty applying to the current problem?  If we were to look at a related problem where we ask "*What is the probability that $5$ is the largest of the picked numbers*" what challenge do you face answering that?

Comment: One way to get insight is to work the problem for a smaller set.  If you replace $10$ by $5$ or even $6$  then you can write down all possible triples and read the answer off, for example.

Comment: Thx @JMoravitz I think I know how to do it. I wasn’t thinking in the right way

Comment: I encourage you to share your attempts so that you can have your answer checked and if anything is off that we can help correct any misconceptions and fill in any gaps if any exist.

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah I usually do but this time I just didn’t know where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalization: what is the expected value of the biggest number if we choose $k$ numbers from $1,2,...n$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
E&=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}\sum_{i=k}^{n}{i\binom{i-1}{k-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}\sum_{i=k}^{n}{k\binom{i}{k}}\\
&=\frac{k}{\binom{n}{k}}\sum_{i=k}^{n}{\binom{i}{k}}\\
&=\frac{k}{\binom{n}{k}}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\\
&=\frac{k}{\binom{n}{k}}\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\\
&=\frac{k}{k+1}(n+1)
\end{aligned}
$$

in Your case, substitute $n=10$ and $k=3$

Comment: I got it, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

The **expected value** of a variable is the average of possible values weighted by their probabilities. It will not necessarily be an whole number even if only whole numbers are possible values.

The largest of the three numbers picked cannot be 1 or 2 because there are insufficient smaller numbers available.

If the largest number is 3 then there is only 1 possible combination for the other numbers (1 2).

If the largest number is 4 then there are 1+2=3 possible combinations for the other numbers (1 2) & (1 3)(2 3).

If the largest number is 5 then there are 1+2+3=6 possible combinations for the other numbers (1 2) & (1 3)(2 3) & (1 4)(2 4)(3 4).

Following the same pattern, if the largest number is 6 then there are 1+2+3+4=10 possible combinations for the other numbers. This pattern is the **triangular numbers**. The next are 15, 21, 28, 36.

The expected value of the largest number picked is therefore 
$$E(X)=\frac{3*1+4*3+5*6+6*10+7*15+8*21+9*28+10*36}{1+3+6+10+15+21+28+36}=\frac{990}{120}=8.25$$