# Expected value elimination tournament

Tags: combinatorics

Wouldn’t it just be 2 since that’s the second highest?

Comment: Must 2 always play in the final? Could 2 be eliminated in the first round?

Comment: How 'random' is the placement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the eight players are divided into two brackets of four. the lowest number of each brackets will advance to the final. since one bracket contains $1$, the question is reduced to finding expected value of lowest number if we take 4 numbers from $2,3,...8$

answer is $2.6$ btw

Answer (score 0):

Well clearly, 8 can't be in the finals. Similarly, 7 can't be in the finals either because there has to be 3 people worse than 7 in the bottom half assuming that 1 is in the top half. We can narrow this down to the fact that 5 is the lowest ranking player that can make it to the finals.

We will use the definition of expectation which is 
\begin{align*}
\sum_x xP(X = x)
\end{align*}
To calculate the probability that 5 is in the finals, we have to calculate the probability that the bottom bracket is just 5,6,7,8. That is quite simple. That is 
\begin{align*}
\frac{{4 \choose 4}}{{7 \choose 4}} = \frac{1}{35}
\end{align*}
The probability that 4 is in the finals is
\begin{align*}
\frac{{1\choose 1}{4 \choose 3}}{{7 \choose 4}} = \frac{4}{35}
\end{align*}
The probability that 3 is in the finals is
\begin{align*}
\frac{{1\choose 1}{5 \choose 3}}{{7 \choose 4}} = \frac{10}{35}
\end{align*}
The probability that 2 is in the finals is
\begin{align*}
\frac{{1\choose 1}{6 \choose 3}}{{7 \choose 4}} = \frac{20}{35}
\end{align*}
Therefore the expected value is 
\begin{align*}
5 \times \frac{1}{35} + 4 \times \frac{4}{35} + 3 \times \frac{10}{35} + 2\times \frac{20}{35}
\end{align*}

Comment: check this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3596825/751970 . you may be interested to find that Your answer equals  $1+(n+1)-\frac{k}{k+1}(n+1)$ for $n=7$ and $k=4$